# Windows 10 can not see HD SATA after ssd installation

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, sata

I had a setup as below

1 SATA 160 gb Bootable (windows 7)
1 SATA 160 gb
1 SATA 350 gb
1 SATA 500 gb

I decided to buy an Samsung evo 256 gb SSD in order to replace the bootable disk
and i performed a clean windows 10 installation.
Although after that i could not see one
of SATA 350 gb or SATA 500 gb. I was obligated to choose only one of these.

Could you please suggest any solution in order to have all the hard disks available.
*note that this is an intel system.*

Comment: Make sure you can physically remove the extra disks and start normally. If not, you need to figure out what your Windows 10 install did to the extra disks.

Comment: I tried all the possible combinations of the hds but the problem remains.

Comment: What I would do here is disconnect all but the new drive and install Windows 10 again.   If you choose to do this, put the computer back together the way it was, back everything up to a big external drive, and then install Windows 10 on the new drive with everything else disconnected.